# Timer based clocks losing seconds. VB Community 2015

Tags: vb.net

My question deals with Timer activated clocks. Upon research the most similar situation is found here:

[Two timers with two different intervals C# Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298520/two-timers-with-two-different-intervals-c-sharp-form)

Situation: I have an application being used for a game. In this game, there are many instances where a user must be able to create clocks and timers that need to be accurate within a second and if clocks, follow UTC Time.

Due to the need for variables to be used across forms, they are declared in a module.

```
Module Global_Variables


    ' String Variables
    ' frmMain
    Public strMDbPath As String

    ' Date & Time Variables
    'frmMain
    Public dtLocalTime As DateTime
    Public dtEveTime As DateTime

End Module
```

"frmMain" the main form, uses two clocks. Clock 1 is local time and clock 2 is UTC time.

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    'Start Eve and Local Time Clocks
    tmrMainTimes.Interval = 1000
    tmrMainTimes.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub mnuSecuredItemEnableAccess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuSecuredItemEnableAccess.Click

    'Show Enable Access Form (frmFirstAccess)
    Dim frmFirstAccess As New frmFirstAccess()
    frmFirstAccess.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub tmrMainTimes_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrMainTimes.Tick

    ''Start Local Time
    'toolstripItemLocalTime.Text = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")

    ''Start Eve (UTC) Time
    'toolstripItemEveTime.Text = Format(Now.ToUniversalTime, "HH:mm:ss")

    dtLocalTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    toolstripItemLocalTime.Text = dtLocalTime

    dtEveTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    toolstripItemEveTime.Text = dtLocalTime
End Sub

Private Sub TimersToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimersToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim frmTimers As New frmTimers()
    frmTimers.ShowDialog()

End Sub
End Class
```

This works great!

The problem lies in the tools section where I am trying to give the user to initiate new timers. When I try to run a separate clock on this form, I initiate a different timer and execute the code in the same way, but the clock seems to lose a second compared to the other clocks.

```
Public Class frmTimers

Private Sub frmTimers_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Start Clock Timer for Timers
    TimersClocksStart.Interval = 1000
    TimersClocksStart.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub TimersClocksStart_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimersClocksStart.Tick


    txtCurrRollEveClock.Text = dtEveTime
End Sub

End Class
```

How do I 1) fix this lag of one second between clocks and timers on multiple forms? 2) prevent it from happening again?

At most, in the application there will ever need to be twenty-five clocks/timers in five forms. At least there will need to be about ten in three forms

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the lag of one second"? The `Tick` event will be called first time one second after you started it. Which means that if you do not start the timers at the exact same second (or tick), they will be off. To fix this you could use just one timer and add multiple/dynamic `Tick` event handlers.

Comment: Timer have a low priority, so they are a bad way to drive clocks if you are expecting them to fire at exactly that interval

Comment: I need clocks across multiple forms to fire at the same time. Can a timer event on one form, fire a timer event on a yet to be opened form? Is that what 'Visual Vincent' means by "To fix this you could use just one timer and add multiple/dynamic Tick event handlers."